# How do i retrieve just the current users "results" right now i getting all of the data i have in parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

```
function publishWindowHandler(){

var query = new Parse.Query(post);
//query.equalTo(currentUser);
query.find({
success:function(results){
  console.log("Successfully retrieved " + user.results);
  for(var i =0; i < results.length; i++){
    var userPost = results[i];
    console.log(userPost.get("User") + " / " + userPost.get("Author") + " / " + userPost.get("Story"));

    var newPost = document.createElement("P");
    newPost.textContent = userPost.get("User") + " / " + userPost.get("Author") + " / " +userPost.get("Title")+ " / " +userPost.get("Story");
    document.getElementById("publishCenter").appendChild(newPost);
  }
 }
})
}
```

when i append child and get the results i only want the results of the post that that user makes at that time and not the entire data base i kinda figure it has something to do with my for loop

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:
query.include("User");
query.equalTo("User", currentUser);

Comment: would i use that instead of my querr.equalto() line ?

Comment: sorry i had not ready your first comment correctly.. also i used the `query.equalTo("User", currentUser);` would i have to also change the way im grabbing my text.content.. to ie (`currentUser.get(User)`) ? im not to sure

Comment: you could use currentUser.get('username'). But since i dont know your database table, i cant tell you exactly. userPost.get("User") would give you an User object not a username.